# Should I answer an old (inactive) question?

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions

I've been browsing around SO, looking for questions that relate to a challenge I'm working on in my current project and came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3933675/3581917), in the 'Similar Questions' panel, that I could fairly confidently answer.  However, the question is three years old, hasn't received a great deal of attention and anyone with similar questions (there are several aspects to the OP's question) could find probably answers to the various components elsewhere.

What would be the accepted way to treat the question:
- Answer it?
- Flag it?  (Not sure what for or even if I can.)
- Ignore it?
- Flame it?
- Something else?

Comment: Note that you can't see a much older answer that pointed out multiple problems with the approach.  I guess Hans Passant deleted his own correct answer because after a comment exchange he felt the OP was beyond help.  (Wrong thing to do, BTW, since the point is to help future readers)

Comment: Given it's 1062 views, I would answer it.   If it only had 10 views and was the same age, then way brother.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

**Answer It**

As you came across that post, there's a possibility that other user can come across the same post too while searching for a similar issue, and hence your answer will help him get a solution.

We do encourage users to answer old questions, and Stackoverflow also awards badges to the users who do so..

*[Revival](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival) - Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more*

*[Necromancer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer) - Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more*

Comment: Agreed, just don't expect many votes for doing so - it's really hard for old questions to bubble up to the "Active" list, so your new answer will be invisible to everyone except Google.

Comment: Necromancer badge achieved, which implies to me that answering it was the correct approach.

Comment: @MikeofSST Ah, the meta-effect :)

Comment: @MikeofSST Answering it and posting a link here was the right approach. ;-) (A link in chat might be more appropriate for future cases)

Comment: Agreed! From a "natural" necromancer (no help from meta). :-)

Comment: I've now got 3 necromancer badges with 12, 59 and 9 upvotes @Mark - I think these were all the old questions that I answered. So, my experience has been that you get a lot more upvotes for answering older questions.

Comment: @Ben I have 12 necromancers myself so I know it's possible, but I've also seen plenty of the reverse - leave a good answer and hear nothing but crickets chirping. I guess it's just the luck of the draw.

Answer (score 34):

Yes you should:

[image: http://xkcd.com/979/]

([*XKCD, Wisdom of the Ancients*](http://xkcd.com/979/))

*"All long help threads should have a sticky globally-editable post at the top saying: DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far..."*

Comment: This is genius!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is plainly yes since there is a Necromancer tag that awards this sort of behavior, at least if the answer is upvoted a certain number of times.

Answer (score -26):

Add a comment pointing to the other answers.  This assists anyone who finds the question in a search, without creating a "zombie".

Comment: Is that notion of "zombie" question mentioned somewhere on Meta or Meta.SO?

Comment: @Bruno - I doubt it, but it's because TPTB choose to pretend the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: It might be worth raising the issue here on Meta. It's not something that I've found to be a problem, even on the tags I monitor regularly (except when there's some serial re-tagging going on). Perhaps displaying both the creation and modification timestamps in the question lists might be a reasonable solution to this problem (and a reasonable feature request).

Comment: @Bruno - Frankly, unless you're part of the "in" crowd, raising an issue like this will just get you grief.  Witness the rapid downvotes I got on this answer.

Comment: I didn't vote on this answer, but I must admit I might downvote something on this issue, simply because I haven't found it to be a problem, it depends on what's suggested. (I would support showing both creation and modif timestamps in the list, though.) I guess people might be downvoting this because you haven't talked much about what you consider a "zombie" and what you consider wrong with them (I know you mentioned them in a comment in another question). I don't entirely disagree with the "in" crowd issue, I've only been active on Meta recently, and it's not been particularly enjoyable.

Comment: [No such thing as an answer being too late.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40709/2509)

Comment: @Bruno Meta is a place where you can expect to be contradicted. It should feel mean exactly, but you will be challenged to defend your position. And there is a lot of history which the older users know from having lived through it. Say your piece firmly but politely and don't worry too much. People can respect that.

Comment: @dmckee, actually, there is such a thing as being too late. If the question was OK, good enough to get an answer, and which a subject that rather on topic, however sufficiently disliked to have been closed. Then, there's no way to provide an answer that could actually much better than what's already there.

Comment: @dmckee, I don't mind the disagreements and contradictions on Meta, that's fair enough. I mind the fact it only seems to represent a minority of us (and that I even have to intervene here): it's the minority that can be bothered spending time on meta instead of helping others and trying to provide useful content on the main site. Recently, I've spent more time on Meta.SO than what I'd normally do on SO itself, and overall, it feels much less gratifying, almost pointless unfortunately.

Comment: @Bruno I don't spend as much time on the various metas now, but for a while (when the site was 1.5--3.5 years old) there was a lot of policy making going on. And I would argue that contributing to good policy is helping people, albeit at a longer remove than answering the question they have right now. You are right, though, that it isn't much fun. Not even when you "win" and much less when you "lose".

Comment: @HotLicks Or TPTB don't think it *is* a problem. The *in* crowd you refer to giving you downvotes is *the community*, which you seem to be at odds with. Perhaps it is not the community's problem, but your own. In fact, the existence of the Necromancer tags *explicity encourages* the behavior you are calling a problem.

Comment: @Tyrsius - You clearly don't know what it's like to spend ten minutes reading a question and composing a well-considered answer, only to realize, just before you hit Submit, that the question is 4 years old and Opie has no doubt gone on to be an iPhone exec or something.

Comment: @HotLicks What does that have to do with whether or not writing that answer and making a "zombie" is a bad thing *for the community*? The value of an answer is to more than the OP, it is to anyone in the future who has that problem.