# Is editing in the relevant parts of a link to a link-only answer acceptable, even preferred?

Tags: discussion, edits, link-only-answers

I recently found one of my edits to a link only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736701/7758804) up for review and was a bit surprised by the votes cast on it. It was approved but 2 out of 5 voters decided to reject with the reason that it should be a comment or answer in its own right.

I agree that it could have been a comment asking the OP to add in the relevant details from the link but why, if I'm willing to do the work, make the process take longer than it has to and bother the OP for the same end result?

Sure, OP might get annoyed that I'm 'putting words in his mouth' but 1) I'm improving SO, 2) he can re-edit to word as he likes and 3) I've added a comment to the answer (and explained the reason in the reason for edit) stating as much.

It could also be argued flagging it to OP teaches him more but he'll be alerted to the edit anyway and will hence still learn that link only answers are discouraged whilst also having an example of how to improve it.

Seems like this is a better way than just flagging.

Does Meta agree? (Did search but can't find similar questions)

Comment: @S.L.Barth indeed that is the suggestion that made me wonder if it was right or not. And yes, I think the way I went about it was very clear and as objective/factual/minimal as possible so as to avoid changing OPs meaning. I don't think the actual question that caused it is needed for context but I know people will like to see it anyway so since someone has already went to the effort or rooting it out let me save others time - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925424/excel-add-in-udf-path-issue/25736701#25736701

Comment: @CodeCaster - The form to ask the question states that the line you have edited is a title and in English titles are capitalised, whether on BuzzFeed or not. However, as no-one else here seems to adhere to this rule I accept your edit and will adjusted my titles in future as I'd rather be consistent than be right! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It was meant kind of tongue-in-cheek, but question titles are never supposed to be written in title case on the Stack Exchange network. I personally find it horribly unreadable when applied, too.

Comment: [citation needed] ;-) I'll admit I missed the tongue-in-cheek-ness to start with and got a bit annoyed at the insinuation, but then I tried to get over myself and laugh it off before commenting, sorry if there are still traces of hateful spite in my reply! Agreed, capital free titles are indeed easier to read and easier to write as well, even if it does pain me to see.

Comment: @honk - Sorry, I appreciate your efforts but I don't feel 'they' is a suitable replacement for 'he'. The joy of being gender neutral is not worth the pain of being pluraly incorrect. Also I prefer the list in line as it adds to how I am aiming the reader to read the question. Agreed with a couple of your other edits but no enough to warrant adding them in.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland: No problem. It was just a suggestion. Feel free to keep your post as you like it.

Comment: Meh, be wary when polishing turds.  Sometimes they're fresh.

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*

Answer (score 31):

You were referring to [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25736701/revisions).

It looks like a good edit; it turned a link-only answer into a complete answer. And the things you said came almost verbatim from the linked page.

There is indeed a risk of putting words into the answerer's mouth. Since the text you added came almost verbatim from the linked article, I think that risk is negligible.

You might want to use blockquotes, to make it clear that you're quoting another source. As an extra benefit, this also helps showing that you're not putting words into the answerer's mouth.

My only word of caution (for future readers): when adding in content from a link, make sure you understand the subject material well enough to do so. To be able to select, with justifiable confidence, which issues need to be in the SO post, and which ones can be safely left out.

Comment: I think your the paragraph is especially important. I've seen edits like this attempted, but the editor didn't know the subject matter well enough. This made the answer completely wrong where if they'd known the subject matter it would have been trivial to grab the relevant parts of the linked page.

Comment: +1. **Please** use blockquotes.

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing wrong with it -- you are improving stuff -- but I would say it's not the *optimum* action you can take.

For any link-only answer, one of three other conditions will be true:

- the information behind the link is relevant and helpful, **and** there's another answer that encapsulates the same information -- [maybe even cites the same resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309559/i-cant-imagine-why-this-naa-flag-was-declined#comment267717_309559)!
- the information is good, but no other answer covers the same ground (in your case, there simply is no other answer)
- the information behind the link is not particularly germane to the problem

In the second case, you have a clear opportunity: **write your own better answer**. Assuming that you have the knowledge to edit in only relevant pieces from the linked content (as S.L. Barth mentioned), you also have the knowledge to outline, summarize, or even ¡gasp! rewrite in your own words that material. The link can be provided as backup, as Atw--d intended.

If you feel that you are somehow "stealing" the link, well, first, competition to write great answers is [one of the gamification principles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265643/603977) that makes the answers here great. Second, you can very easily include a mention: "userNNNN provided a link <link> that has some good information, but just to explain a few of the points there *blah, blah, blah*."

In the first situation -- an existing answer with the useful info already inline -- the link-only answer really [presents only negative value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/159251). The best course of action is voting on the two answers, and flagging the link-only answer for removal (or voting "delete" if you have that privilege). You might consider not using an NAA flag, though; a custom flag along the lines of "The information behind the link here is completely encapsulated in an existing answer to this question <link/to/answer>; this answer offers no help beyond what's already available and should be removed" explains very clearly what the issue is.

(For the third bullet above, well, that's a just a flat-out unhelpful answer. Editing won't change that anyways.)